# How do I create a 'asp:RegularExpressionValidator' to prevent a user from using hashtags and ampersands?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I have tried

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regJobTitle" runat="server"  
ControlToValidate="Job_TitleTextBox"
CssClass="required" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" 
ErrorMessage="Please remove (&) or (#)"
SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationExpression="^[^&#]*$" />
```

When I run the script the error message will not display.

Comment: Though I can't be sure, I think the issue you're having is that with the validator you need to remove the begin/end of the line, so change it to: `[^&#]*`.

Comment: I think the page cache was the culprit here. I restarted chrome several times after deleting history and cookies and finally restarted my PC and boom...it works

Comment: Well, isn't that awesome?!